# How to use variables in LUA 5.1 Touchosc

Tags: lua

I'm trying, to wrap my head around Touchosc and script based on LUA 5.1.
I have a number of labels, called song0, song1, song2, and so on. I'm trying to set different values in these, using

```lua
local text = 'Smoke On The Water'
for i = 1, 2 do
    self.children.pager1.children.main.children.song[i].values.text = text
end
```

but that gives me an error.
:-) I do need help.

Finn

Comment: and you think that "an error" is an appropriate description? why do you think you are provided with an error message that usually tells you what you're doing wrong at which location? come on, how can you expect any help if you post syntactically correct code but nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the actual error, it's difficult to say what the problem is, but if I have to venture a guess, then try replacing `...children.song[i].values...` with `...children["song"..i].values...`. Since there is no table `song`, you just need to generate dynamic field names.